# How to convert KTX image to PNG image?

Tags: c++, image, png, qimage

I am in middle of development.
I have loaded available KTX images using libktx files. But now i have to convert these images into PNG images (i want to show as PNG images). So i need to convert these "ktx" images to png images.

loaded decoded ktx(etc2 format) data into char*. And I am using QImage for forming png image.
like, using char* of loaded ktx image, create a new QImage with respective size.
But when I did it, I am having a different image which is not as same as of original image.

Creating Qimage.

```
QImage(uchar *data, int width, int height, Format format, QImageCleanupFunction cleanupFunction = Q_NULLPTR, void *cleanupInfo = Q_NULLPTR)
```